# How can I overcome the "No such file or directory: '.keras/keras.json'" error on Google Colab?

Tags: python, keras, google-colaboratory

As the title clearly describes, I'm not able to access the `Keras` configuration (`keras.json`) file in order to change its backend as getting the `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.keras/keras.json'` error. How can I access this file on `Google Colab`?

Here is my script:

```
with open('.keras/keras.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  print(f.read())
```

p.s. The related questions did not include any information regarding this. So, might be something new regarding the platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That json file is (usually) in `"~/.keras"` directory.
So,

```py
import os
with open(os.path.expanduser('~/.keras/keras.json'), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  print(f.read())
```

I get on my colab the following.

```
{
    "epsilon": 1e-07, 
    "floatx": "float32", 
    "image_data_format": "channels_last", 
    "backend": "tensorflow"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To show the file

```
!cat /root/.keras/keras.json
```

To write to the file

```
%%writefile /root/.keras/keras.json
{
    "epsilon": 1e-07, 
    "floatx": "float32", 
    "image_data_format": "channels_last", 
    "backend": "tensorflow"
}
```